# Selecionar itens de um array baseado em outro

Tags: php

Boa noite, possuo dois arrays.

Um com as chaves, Ex:

```
$array = [
 'casa',
 'porta,
 'quarto'
];
```

E outros com chaves e valores, Ex:

```
$array = [
 'casa' => 'amarela',
 'porta => 'marrom',
 'quarto' => 'azul,
 'cachorro' => 'bidu',
 'sofa' => 'cinza'
];
```

O que eu quero fazer: Usar o primeiro array para montar um terceiro array com as chaves existentes no primeiro e no segundo, descartando os outros itens do segundo array.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
$array = [
'casa' => 'amarela',
 'porta => 'marrom',
 'quarto' => 'azul
];
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer de pelo menos duas formas diferentes, uma direta com a sintaxe mais simples usando [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), percorrendo o array [ 'casa', 'porta, 'quarto' ], e verificando com [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset) se cada valor do array existe como índice do segundo array, para atribuir no novo gerado.

```
<?php

    $partesCasa = ['casa', 'porta', 'quarto'];
    $cores = ['casa' => 'amarela', 'porta' => 'marrom', 'quarto' => 'azul', 'cachorro' => 'bidu', 'sofa' => 'cinza'];
    $novoArray = [];

    foreach ($partesCasa as $parte) {
    if (isset($cores[$parte])) {
            $novoArray[$parte] = $cores[$parte];
        }            
    }

    print_r($novoArray);
```

Também pode usar um conhecimento mais aprofundado da linguagem e gerar o novo array diretamente usando as funções [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key), que retorna os dados do primeiro array passado como parâmetro, comparando com as chaves do segundo array passado como parâmetro, como as chaves do primeiro array são numéricas, usa-se [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip) para transformar os valores em chaves e as chaves em valores.

```
<?php

    $partesCasa = ['casa', 'porta', 'quarto'];
    $cores = ['casa' => 'amarela', 'porta' => 'marrom', 'quarto' => 'azul', 'cachorro' => 'bidu', 'sofa' => 'cinza'];
    $novoArray = array_intersect_key($cores, array_flip($partesCasa));

    print_r($novoArray);
```

Veja os dois exemplos funcionando: [ideone](https://ideone.com/doy3ZK)